# PHP Internal Memory Bloat

Tags: php, memory, memory-management

I have a need to process a some large files say 50MB each.  I have found that PHP functions use up large portions of memory.  In the below example the memory used by PHP's functions ends up being four (4) times the file size.  I can understand the transient usage of twice  the memory size of the file, but not four times.   In the end PHP blows out the memory_limit.   While I can increase the PHP memory_limit it is not a good long term solution as I may have to process larger files, and in a production environment having PHP gobble up 400MB per process is not desirable.

Code:

```
$buf = '';
report_memory(__LINE__);

$buf = file_get_contents('./20MB.pdf');
report_memory(__LINE__);

base64_encode($buf);
report_memory(__LINE__);

urlencode($buf);
report_memory(__LINE__);

function report_memory($line=0) {
    echo 'Line: ' . str_pad($line,3) . '  ';
    echo 'Mem: '  . str_pad(intval(memory_get_usage()/1024     ) . 'K',8) . '  ';
    echo 'Peak: ' . str_pad(intval(memory_get_peak_usage()/1024) . 'K',8) . '  ';
    echo "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
Line: 4    Mem: 622K      Peak: 627K
Line: 7    Mem: 21056K    Peak: 21074K
Line: 10   Mem: 21056K    Peak: 48302K
Line: 13   Mem: 21056K    Peak: 82358K
```

One can see that for a 20MB file the current memory usage hovers at 21MB, while the peak memory usage jumps up to an insane 82MB.

The PHP functions used in the example are arbitrary, I can easily swap in str_replace, is_string, gettype, etc with the same results.

The question is how can I keep PHP from doing this?

The environment is CentOS 6.6 running a stock PHP 5.3.3.

Thanks for any insight.

Comment: assuming you're running standard apache+php swap to nginx+php-fpm that'll reduce the memory usage.  Alternatively you can swap to nginx+hhvm it'll use more memory but the processes will be completed much faster.  If you're using it via CLI then there's not much you can do short of a custom php compile  to make the most of it but that won't make massive difference.

Comment: As `base64_encode($buf);` is creating a base64 encoded copy of the data from `$buf` to return to your script (that's what you're actually telling PHP to do when you call that function), then it is going to have to store that copy in memory so that it can be returned to your script.... what do you actually expect PHP To do?

Comment: I need to keep this within the context of PHP, php-fpm and hhvm are not an option.  I fail to see how nginx will solve a PHP memory issue. Exactly what compile time options for PHP would you recommend to solve this PHP memory issue?

Comment: Since the memory is dropping back down again to a fairly consistent level, it seems more likely those functions just want a lot of memory rather than some kind of memory leak.

Comment: @Mark Baker: As stated in the OP, I can understand that PHP will make a copy of the string as it processes it, effectively doubling the memory usage.  That is not the issue.  It is the four times memory usage that is the issue.  And again, it doesn't matter which PHP functions, base64_encode or otherwise, are used. This is a wider PHP internal issue.

Comment: @OddEssay: Memory leak or not. _"Just want a lot of memory"_ is the issue.

Comment: Well you suggest that `is_string()` and `gettype()` also gobble up large amounts of memory, but that should certainly not be the case... if a call to those functions doubles memory usage (no matter how temporary) then there's a serious problem, but I see no evidence of that.... and can you please show which functions are being called on line 24: I can only account to line 21 from your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're url-encoding. Given that your PDF is basically "random" binary garbage, **MANY** of the bytes in there are non-printable. That means you're going from a one byte "binary" character to 3+ byte URL-encoded string. Given you've got a 20meg PDF, it's no surprise that tripling the amount of text in there is going to bloat your memory. Remember that PHP has to keep TWO copies of your PDF while it's working: the original "raw" version, and the working copy of whatever transform you're doing on it.

Assuming a worst-case "every single character gets encoded", your 20meg PDF will convert to a 60meg url-encoded string, causing a 20+60 = 80 meg peak usage, even though that 60meg encoded version is immediately tossed away.